# jQuery Mobile on tap isn't detected on check boxes

Tags: jquery, mobile

I need user taps detected no matter which element is being tapped. The code below works fine except for on jQuery Mobile checkboxes.

```
 $(document).on( 'tap', function(e){
      function
 });
```

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1a" id="checkbox-1a" checked="">
                            <label for="checkbox-1a">Default Reason</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2a" id="checkbox-2a">
                            <label for="checkbox-2a">Reason Two</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-3a" id="checkbox-3a">
                            <label for="checkbox-3a">Retail Store</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-4a" id="checkbox-4a">
                            <label for="checkbox-4a">Reason Four</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-5a" id="checkbox-5a">
                            <label for="checkbox-5a">Need Info</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-6a" id="checkbox-6a">
                            <label for="checkbox-6a">System Trial</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-7a" id="checkbox-7a">
                            <label for="checkbox-7a">Medical Office</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-8a" id="checkbox-8a">
                            <label for="checkbox-8a">Last Reason</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: did you mistype your function...? Post your code for the tap eventHandler

Comment: Instead of 'tap' try 'click' or 'vclick' in the event handler.  Clicks should be interpreted as a tap.  You could also do `$(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){ } );`